# table.rows.length not working in mozilla firefox but working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, cross-browser

```
var otable, orow, ocol;
otable = eval(document.all.tabmenu); 
for(var ictr=otable.rows.length-1;ictr>=0;ictr--) --> error
otable.deleteRow(ictr);
```

There is an classic asp project in which a javascript functionand is creating two hyperlinks (add,delete).
    tabmenu is a table, while in google chrome when i debug then otable.rows.length = 2 which is working fine 
    but unfortunately in firefox otable.rows.length = 0 , i am not able to understand it.
    Need help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not `document.all` collection in FF. Instead of `eval(document.all.tabmenu)` use `document.getElementById('tabmenu')`, which will work in any browser.

Comment: @rohitsingh You do have an `id` for the `<table>` you're trying to refer? Also drop the `eval()` totally out, it's useless and might be even dangerous...

Comment: @rohitsingh And not working in FF? Definitely it should. What's the error message(s)?